# "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." error

Tags: sql-server

I have the following query:

```
DECLARE @Month int
DECLARE @Year int

set @Month = 2 
set @Year = 2004  

Declare @MonthStartDate datetime
declare @MonthEndDate datetime  

set @MonthStartDate = 'select DATEADD(month,@Month-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))' 

set @MonthEndDate = 'select DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)))'
```

return @MonthStartDate  , @MonthEndDate

But it returns:

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."

What's wrong here?

Comment: can you explain what are you trying to do here ? The error is because you are assigning a query string to datetime data type

Comment: Can you rephrase your question in the format of sample input and then the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can also use as follow..

```
select @MonthStartDate = DATEADD(month,@Month-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))
select @MonthEndDate = DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use DateTime expression instead of string literal. Just remove quotes:

```
DECLARE @Month int

DECLARE @Year int

set @Month = 2 

set @Year = 2004  

Declare @MonthStartDate datetime
declare @MonthEndDate datetime  

set @MonthStartDate = DATEADD(month,@Month-1,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0))

set @MonthEndDate = DATEADD(day,-1,DATEADD(month,@Month,DATEADD(year,@Year-1900,0)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Query (Since you don't have enough Description on the Question ) What I understood is that you are trying to get the First and Last day of a Given month. If you are using a SQL Server Version 2012 or Above, then you have an Inbuild Function called `EOMONTH()` which can be used to calculate the End of any given month. Otherwise, you may try the below method on any Version on SQL Server

```
Declare @MonthStartDate datetime,
        @MonthEndDate datetime,
        @Year int,
        @Month int --It's Better to Declare all the variables in the same space for easy handling

SELECT
    @Month = 2,
    @Year = 2004  -- Common Assignments can be done together

;WITH MNT
AS
(
    SELECT
        MonthStartDate = CAST(@Month AS VARCHAR(20))+'/01/'+CAST(@Year AS VARCHAR(20)) -- Hardcoded Day as 1 since Month Start always at 1
)
SELECT
    @MonthStartDate = MonthStartDate,
    @MonthEndDate = DATEADD(DAY,-1,DATEADD(MONTH,1,MonthStartDate))
    FROM MNT
```

Comment: "Hardcoded Day as 1 since Month Start always at 1" - except for all of the SQL Server installs/users who don't use `m/d/y` format, in which case you've hard coded the month instead. If you're *going* to use string conversions (and there really is no need here), at least use an *unambiguous* format such as `YYYYMMDD` which is always interpreted the same no matter what date/language settings are in force.